# OfficeJS - Outlook add-in getting internal error when using addFileAttachmentFromBase64Async on Outlook for Mac client only

Tags: macos, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook add-in that calls addFileAttachmentFromBase64Async() and it's returning

```
{"name":"Internal Error","message":"An internal error has occurred.","code":5001}
```

but only when specifically testing on Outlook for Mac. (latest version "16.57.22011101" and New Outlook toggled on)

This API call works great in Windows client, and Web client. The full method call is

```
public createAttachment(attachmentInfo: Attachment, base64Content: string): Promise<boolean> {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (typeof this._item?.addFileAttachmentFromBase64Async === 'function') {
    // safe to use the function
    this._item.addFileAttachmentFromBase64Async(
      base64Content,
      attachmentInfo.name,
      { isInline: false },
      (asyncResult) => {
        if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          reject(false);
          console.error(
            'Error adding attachment: ' + JSON.stringify(asyncResult.error)
          );
        }
      }
    );
  } else {
    // item does not have addFileAttachmentFromBase64Async()
    console.error('wrong command surface?', this._item);
    reject('Could not add attachment. Wrong command surface for item?');
  }
});
```

}

Anyone have any ideas?

Edit: This seems to only occur when composeType is coincidentally 'forward'.

Comment: Have you checked whether requirement set 1.8 is supported at runtime?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev, yes i check if requirement set 1.10 is supported at runtime.

Comment: When and where do you call this method? What event handler do you use?

Comment: The code around this call [is presented above and] using a callback and asyncResult

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. We are able to reproduce this issue internally. It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point.